# UITabbarController problem

Tags: iphone

I Have two xib files named firstView and SecondView ........
I implemented these into tabbarcontroller items...Now its work fine..
When i select firsttabbaritem firstView was loaded also select second tabbaritem its loaded secondview...

i have back button in the SecondView ...If some one clicked these back button means how can i load firstView?....

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance........

Answer (score 1):

I think that Apple's usability guidelines might encourag you not to use a back button to change tabs.

If you must  - look at UITabController.selectedTabIndex

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not how your users are going to expect the interface to work. Back buttons are for navigating back up a NavigationController stack. A Tab Bar is for navigating between completely independent NavigationController stacks.

Think about it in terms of a browser. If I go from Site A to Site B, then switch tabs... I don't want my NEW tab to go back to Site A.

You really ought to seriously consider what it is that you are trying to do, and whether or not it makes any sense to an end user.